# Change configuration at runtime in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am new to Service Fabric and don't fully understand the concepts but I am looking at a way to change the configuration at runtime like is possible in Cloud Services and App Services without performing an upgrade (and having to up-version the config file to do so).

For example, imagine that one setting is "Email destination", which might be changed several times a month and should be picked up automatically by the service.

It seems that ConfigurationPackageModifiedEvent is only fired for upgrades and that there is no other way to update and trigger this.

Otherwise, is there another way to relatively simply update a value that the service is using?

Comment: Database could be a best place to store frequently modifying data.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: The project is parked for now! By the time I raise it back to life, things might have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that SF team went with us that any change should be a versions change. That includes configuration packages as well. You could deploy configuration package only to advice what you need w/o modifying the code or data packages.
Alternatively, using an external source of data could be an option. You could put it behind a dedicated service in SF to abstract the details.